# bootstrap twitter glyphicon shadow css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Can anyone help me get some bootstrap glyphicons buttons look right?
I am trying to add some shadow to them in CSS but the shadow goes around the button, not the icon itself. Is there a way to make the shadow around the icon (or at least the form of the icon)?
Thank you,
Alex

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=JimDp87hIh). It is messy but if you look at the button (i) (Information)(top right corner) you should be able to see the problem. `<button class="btn btn-link" title="Help" style="background:none; color:yellow; position: absolute; right: 12px; top: 3px; left: auto; " onclick="myFunction()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="background:none !important; box-shadow: -4px -4px 5px white;"></span></button>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the icons are rendered using a custom font you have to use `text-shadow`:

```
.glyphicon{
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/qLQs9/6/)**

Comment: Great! That was it! Now is it possible for me. Thank you! Is it possible to reverse the text-shadow too? Like reverse the i?